# Flyway migration test particular migration data transformation

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, flyway

I have migration that transforms complex jsonb object into another jsonb object but with different structure and store it in new column `existing_column_name_v2`.

How to test that to make sure I did everything ok?

Here are my steps I am thinking right now:

- Apply migrations up to the last one
- Feed the data
- Apply last migration
- Run tests in language of choice and compare results

I am not sure how to execute just migrations I need with Flyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To migrate to a specific version, use `flyway migrate target=<version>` as described in the [Flyway docs](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/target).